# box-shadow no se muestra en el navegador

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, box-shadow

estoy practicando un navbar y tengo que agregarle un box-shadow en el borde inferior, pero tengo un problema con los navegadores (Edge y Chrome) y es que no me muestran el box-shadow, pero al ingresar el mismo código en el preview de la página "Stackoverflow" el código se ejecuta sin problemas, el box-shadow aparece.

Entonces supongo que debe ser un problema de los navegadores(?)
Ya borré el historial y el caché y las cookies.

Gracias por tu tiempo

```css
.navbar {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
}
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing page Book</title>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link  type="text/css" href="assets/main.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> 
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Fazt logo" style="width: 20%;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JAVASCRIP -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN:

Me faltaba incluir en el link css la carpeta "css"

Lo descubrí gracias a éste [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4jOgmIgOfA&ab_channel=LearnWithAliHossain)

Answer (score 3):

Intenta agregar las dos líneas del final, a veces los navegadores viejitos se manejan con esa propiedad de css.

```
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;

 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;

}
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: Buena respuesta, creo que la enriquecería mas si agregas alguna fuente de la cual pueda leer el OP mas al respecto como esta: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix

Comment: Ok, lo tendre en cuenta. :D @BetaM

Comment: Al final la solución era agregar la carpeta donde estaba alojado el archivo css, o sea:  <!--CUSTOM CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> lo descubrí gracias a: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4jOgmIgOfA&ab_channel=LearnWithAliHossain